# Intercept Cookie Login in ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using OWIN to configure my MVC 5 authentication using

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
    IAppBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication(AuthenticationType = 
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    });
}
```

... and sign on users using

```cs
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, 
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { 
    IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

In my `User` model I have a flag, `Inactive`, which when set by an admin should prevent the user from logging in. This is not a problem when users login without asking to be remembered (without setting a cookie) since I can retrieve whether they are inactive or not and act based on that.

The problem is when they login and ask to be remembered (ticking 'Remember me' checkbox). The next time they browse the site, ASP.net automatically logs them in. Where should I intercept this procedure to check whether the user is inactive or not?

I read about `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` in global.asax

```cs
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //do stuff with User.Identity here
}
```

But this method seem to be called twice, sometimes 3 times. Also I want to be able to see whether the authentication came from a cookie or by entering credentials in the login page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume you have very few "InActive" users. I would just store them in Cache and check it on every request. If the user happens to be InActive then log them out. In memory is better than relying on cookie information.

Comment: Khalid, he was not asking for improvement recommendations. He was asking how to determine if he authentication came from a cookie or by entering credentials in the login page.